# What does "const& X", where X is a struct mean in method prototype?

Tags: c++, methods, constants

I'm reading a book Statistical computing in C++ and R (Eubank and Kupresanin, 2012) and there is a following exercise:

"3.27. Write a code for a struct `X` that has two integer member elements `a` and `b`. One method for the struct should have the prototype

```
bool compare(const& X)
```

The `compare` method should compare two `X` objects and return the object that has a smaller value for the `a` member."

Problem here is that I don't understand what `const& X` is supposed to represent, and it seems that g++ compiler doesn't understand it either as it gives an error. Should that mean something or is it just a typo? My solution which ignores the const& part, is like this:

```
struct X{
    int a;
    int b;
    X(int A, int B);
    bool compare(X x);
};

X::X(int A, int B){
    a=A;
    b=B;
}

bool X::compare(X x){
    if(x.a>(*this).a){
        return true;
    } else return false;
}

int main(){
    X y(5,0);
    X z(2,3);
    if(y.compare(z))
        cout << "y.a = "<<y.a<< " which is larger than z.a = "<< z.a<<endl;
    else
        cout << "y.a = "<<y.a<< " which is smaller than z.a = "<< z.a<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Which seems to work ok.

Comment: Use `bool compare(const X&)` as the prototype, where `X` is some class or type name.

Comment: Beware: in the STL, `std::string::compare` returns an `int` that is negative if the left-hand string is inferior to the right-hand one, positive if the left-hand string is superior to the right-hand one and zero if the two string are equal; like `memcmp` and `strcmp` do in C. As such, I would be wary of using the name `compare` with a return type of `bool`. `lessThan` is also more explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have transcribed it correctly, there is a typo, but the existence of `&` isn't it. It should be:

```
bool compare(const X&)
```

It is a *reference type*. That is, `const X&` is a "reference to `const X`". Taking a reference type parameter means that the `X` object that is passed in isn't copied - the object you see inside the function *is* the object that was passed in from outside.

Comment: Sure it's copied, you're copying the reference. All parameters in C++ are passed "by value" if you go by textbook definitions.

Comment: @Blindy I disagree with your interpretation. The caller gives as an argument an expression that denotes an `X` object. That object is either passed by value or reference. There's no reference being passed by value (as in Java). It is creating a reference to the object denoted by the argument.

Comment: @Blindy: nothing is copied, you can't copy a reference. Sure, internally this may be done by copying a pointer (though the assembly guys don't call it this way: they say _moving an address_), but often it will only be calculated on the spot – when the `X` object resides on the stack, its address is obtained by adding an offset to the stack pointer. Anyway C++' semantics don't specify anything like that, it's implementation-defined.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I though. In some point of messing around I forgot the whole & out of the prototype also. And of course const won't hurt either...

Comment: @Hemmo A `const` reference is important. It allows you to pass a temporary `X`. A non-`const` reference cannot bind to a temporary object.

Comment: /shrug, you can disagree if you want, but the pointer **is** copied the same as any "value" object. The whole by value/by reference dichotomy is extremely arbitrary, and comes nowhere close to covering the *semantics* of parameter passing, as it claims to in the books you're referencing. Just look at how many combinations of parameter decorations there are in C#.

Comment: "The pointer" isn't the variable being passed. There's no pointer involved theoretically: I don't see a (legal) problem if the compiler emitted code that, at each function call, modified the function's code to directly use the addresses of the parameters, so that the function itself doesn't do a dereference. It would be inefficient, but it just happens that pointers are a good way to implement the semantics of pass-by-reference. It's not like with arrays, where you pass an actual pointer (with its own address!) to screw around with.

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely a typo, they probably meant `const X &`, as in a reference to a constant `X`:

```
bool compare(const X &)
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax

```
bool compare(const X&){ }
```

means a constant "reference" to X;
A reference is an alias for a variable. It works like a pointer, but is connected to the object it references for its lifetime. You'll change the object which is passed to the function like you would be using a pointer.